# GVM uses hidden directory

Tags: macos, grails, gvm

I am mac / Grails noob.
I used the GVM to install Groovy and Grails on a Mac.
When I do:

```
admins-MacBook-Pro-5:~ me$ which grails
/Users/me/.gvm/grails/current/bin/grails
```

I am just wondering why does gvm use a hidden directory and can this cause me any problems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's normal, it's a standard practice, and doesn't make any problem.

> Configuration files that reside in users' home directories are hidden by default as a means of protecting them from accidental damage or deletion.

From: http://web.archive.org/web/20071017224738/http://bellevuelinux.org/hidden_file.html

Most other development tools use hidden directories too:

```
> ls -a ~/
.gradle .grails .gvm .ivy2 .lein .m2 .rvm
```

Comment: thanks I guess the ~ is for home and then the / is for include hidden?  Correct?

Comment: Thanks. What is the / for then?

Comment: You could skip it, actually :) I always use `/` at the end of directory path (`~/` == `~`, `/tmp/` == `/tmp`, etc)